# pygame doesn't show up

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I have recently installed PyGame in Python, but something strange happens. When I import it and use it in the terminal, it works fine, but when I try to use it in `idle` it doesn't work at all. Does someone know why does this happens?

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

win = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))
```

Exits with the error:

```
>Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/USER/PycharmProjects/Primer Python/Basico/pygame.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pygame
  File "C:\Users\USER\PycharmProjects\Primer Python\Basico\pygame.py", line 2, in <module>
    pygame.init()
AttributeError: module 'pygame' has no attribute 'init'
```

Comment: Did you name your file 'pygame.py'? Rename it to something else like 'pygame_test.py' and it should work all fine.

Comment: Thanks that made it work XD, sorry for being such a noob

Comment: No problem. I've made that mistake and I've seen my classmates with that mistake too. It seems just too easy to fix :D